# Difference between org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement / org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, package

I've been using products around Hadoop, but new to developing an application with them using Java.

I'd like to use some classes like HiveStatement, but found that there are the same name classes with different packages.

ex) `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement`, `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement`.

I noticed this when trying to cast a Statement object into HiveStatement. I was trying to cast a object into `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement`, but casting into `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement` seems right in my case.

What's the difference, and why do two similar packages exist?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.hadoop.hive` is the old Java package name for Apache Hive, for example version 0.8.x of the Hive JDBC driver.

Around the 1.0.0 release time frame, the package name changed.

You should use `org.apache.hive` for newer versions.

Comment: Thank you @ck1, then I'll use `org.apache.hive`.